# Add UIButtons programmatically then sort them by name like Swipes app

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have an application that allows me to add buttons programmatically, so far I have these buttons being added a certain number of pixels away from each other.

I was looking through my apps and opened Swipes app for to do lists. When adding a new task, you press an add button that allows you to create a new button. The button is then inserted among the other buttons in an alphabetic order. Once there are too many buttons for one row, it begins inserting the buttons below to create a second row of buttons

This is exactly what I'm looking for as far as functionality goes in my app, I just don't know how I would do it.

To be more clear, I'm pretty sure I know how to sort things alphabetically, but i wouldn't know how to extend that to the positioning of buttons.

In advanced, thank you so much for your assistance. I really appreciate it.

[image: A really quick mockup of what it should basically look like]

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically, there are a number of ways you can approach this. I would create two methods, addButton() and redrawButtons(). For addButton(), it will need to look at the the last button's position, and the size of the view frame, and determine mathematically whether a new button will fit to the right (or below for that matter). Based on where you need to add, right or below, you need to place the button there. I'd really recommend using Auto Layout and key off the last button as the 'toItem'.

For redrawButtons(), you will just be responding to events that change the frame size, e.g. device rotation. You could just walk through your list of buttons, calling addButton() on each one to place it properly.

You'll also have to deal with running out of room below. You may look at using ScrollView. If you want to avoid most position the math, you might want to look at CollectionView. Without specific code examples, that's about the most I can offer.